# I am trying to connect to MS access on network server using excel vba and having the following error

Tags: excel, vba

connection string:

```
oconn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\10.123.24.44\MS\Test.mdb"
```

it gives the following error:

> 80004005 could not find installable ISAM

Comment: Search this site for **could not find installable ISAM**. Do none of the  existing answers (177 of them) solve your problem? (The very first thing you should always do when you get an error message you don't understand is Googie it - it's highly unlikely you're the first one that's ever seen it. It doesn't appear you did so.)

Comment: Do you have all the appropriate references enabled?

Comment: yes I do ,I have all them enabled

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) or try different provider:

```
oconn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\10.123.24.44\MS\Test.mdb"
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/